# CATransaction duration not working

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I set a few CALayer transform and bounds modifications, within a CATransaction. However, regardless the method I use (key-value, setAnimationDuration) there is no animation, the changes are done, but immediately without transition.
Do you have any idea why?
Thanks!

```
   /* CALayer*layer=[CALayer layer];
        layer.bounds =AnUIImageView.bounds;
        layer.contents=AnUIImageView.layer.contents;
        [AnotherUIImageView.layer addSublayer:layer];

        CGPoint thecentre=AnUIImageView.center;

        CALayer* layerInTarget=[AnotherUIImageView.layer.sublayers lastObject];
        [layerInTarget setPosition:[self.view convertPoint:thecentre toView:AnotherUIImageView]];
        AnUIImageView.layer.hidden=YES;
```

*/ // the code above works, i show it to be complete

```
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f]
                         forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
       layerInTarget.position=[self.view convertPoint:AnotherUIImageView.center toView:AnotherUIImageView];
       layerInTarget.transform=CATransform3DMakeScale(0.6,0.6,0.6);
        [CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CALayer`s that are associated with a `UIView` (as in, they're accessed via `view.layer`) do not participate in implicit animations, regardless of how you configure your `CATransaction`. You either need to use explicit animations (using the appropriate subclass of `CAAnimation`) or you need to use UIView animations.

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware of it. Nevertheless, I changed my previous code and modified the layer with implicit animation BEFORE adding it to my UIImageView. Nothing changed: the layer is modified, but immediately. Bad day today, isn't it...

Comment: OK, finally it did work, and i was also helped by this question:[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981676/catransaction-layer-changes-but-does-not-animate)